# CefSharp language list settings don't affect JavaScript

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I want to be able to change the language used by browser windows (and reload the page, without restarting the application).  I'm currently using CefSharp 69.

My first attempt was to call `Cef.Shutdown()` and then `Cef.Initialize()` again with a different `Locale` in the settings (since this appears to be the only way to set that value).  (Of course, closing all the existing browsers first and creating them again afterwards.)  However it appears that calling Initialize after Shutdown crashes with an unmanaged memory exception, so that's a no-go.  (This seems like a bug.)

My second attempt was to set the `browser.BrowserSettings.AcceptLanguageList` after creating the browser but before navigating it.  While this does appear to update the value sent in the `Accept-Language` header as expected, it does absolutely nothing to the JS `navigator.languages` and `navigator.language` properties on the resulting page, which remain reporting the old language.  (This seems like another bug.)

My third attempt was to set a `RequestContext` and then call SetPreference for `intl.accept_languages`.  This does set JS `navigator.languages` and `navigator.language`, but doesn't send any `Accept-Language` header.  (This seems like another bug.)

So currently I've managed to cobble together something that seems to work as expected by doing **both** the second and third thing, but this seems entirely ridiculous.

---

I subsequently tried updating to CefSharp 91 (the latest currently available).  This behaves mostly the same, except that setting `intl.accept_languages` appears to do both things now, while setting `AcceptLanguageList` still only affects the request header and not JS.

Comment: Calling Cef.Initialize after Cef.Shutdown is not supported and should throw a meaningful exception. I'll fix that shortly. As for AcceptLanguageList it simply maps to https://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/_cef_browser_settings_t.html#accept_language_list we simply set the value. There was some changes recently https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/commits/ddf5446588e8c1acc45dcdc6b2d546da88f98054 it's possibly some extra tweaks are required. You can raise an issue on https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues?status=new&status=open

Comment: It *should* be supported to re-Initialize after Shutdown.  How else are you supposed to change the Locale to make it load a new locale pak?  There doesn't appear to be any other way to do that.

Comment: It's my understanding that it's a limitation of how chromium is designed. From memory you'll need restart your application to change the Locale. Your welcome to continue the discussion on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php from a CefSharp point of view the best I can do is throw an exception explaining the limitation.

Comment: You can try using DevTools to to change the Locale. https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/#method-setLocaleOverride https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3165 It's a long shot, worth a try.